# Why does "&" have a red background in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext3

Why does "&" have a red background in Sublime Text? Are there any problems with that?

[image: screen shot showing "&" in white on red]

Comment: @user202729: I didn't say it shouldn't be clear and useful without the screen shot! You said the OP shouldn't post screen shots of code; I was just pointing out that actually in this case it's relevant (usually it's not!)

Comment: Without the surrounding code (have you read the MCVE page) it's hard to guess. | You can [edit] the question to make it better. Consider reading [ask] and [SO question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: I'm sure it's enough to post `plans & pricing` as text and say that the & is highlighted in the IDE. No-one needs a proof or an illustration to understand what the problem is.

Comment: Anyway, in theory & needs to be `&amp;` in HTML. In practice it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @JJJ Actually the picture was pretty helpful in determining what the issue was, as it shows *exactly* how the highlighting was done - otherwise we'd be left guessing how accurate the description was (e.g. did the user really mean "underlined in red", which might mean some sort of syntax error...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are editing HTML.

In HTML, "&" has a special meaning, just as "<" in "<a href...>" etc.

It can be used to encode special characters, such as "®" ("&reg;"), or accents ("è" - "&egrave;"), or in fact any Unicode character.

If you don't use it like that, most browsers will usually display it as a plain "&", but that's not guaranteed. If you just want a "&" you should quote it by doing "&amp;", to stop the special interpretation.